# LINQ/Projection - How to sort TableA by non FK column id/name field per TableB?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

How can I use LINQ/Projection to sort a list of A objects that contain an id field that references table/object B (B contains id and name).

I want to sort list of A objects that contain B by B.name?

Model (pseudo)

```
public class A
{
   public int AId {get; set;}
   public Nullable<int> BId {get; set;}
}
public class B
{
   public int BId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Code in some controller passing in a list of A's that contain B's but sort them by B.Name?

```
var list = db.As.OrderBy(x => x.BId->References.Name);  // Way wrong but using something similar
return(list.ToList()
```

Basically, looking for the equivalent of this (using projection join or OrderBy from above):

```
        var q1 =
             from a in db.As
             join b in db.Bs on a.BId equals b.BId
             orderby b.Name   // <- Need this to sort by B's name
             select c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right that you are looking for the equivalent to the LINQ query you have already written above, only that it is based on extension methods instead?

In this case the following should work:

```
var list = db.As.Where(a => a.BId.HasValue)
                .Join(db.Bs, a => a.BId.Value, b => b.BId, (a, b) => new { a, b.Name })
                .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
                .Select(r => r.a);
```

I've also added a check to make sure A.BId is not null before getting its value.

Just curious: why can't you use your LINQ query (with the only difference of selecting a instead of c)?

Comment: Awesome! Mainly for interest and to see if there is a performance difference.  Very cool, thanks again!  BTW - The 'c' was a typo, should have been an 'a'.